# What is the difference between fcgi_stdio and fcgiapp?

Tags: c++, c, fastcgi, lighttpd

I am trying to get started with fastcgi development, therefor I download the reference implementation of `libfcgi` and tried to get a testprogram to run with `lighttpd`. Since `fcgi_stdio` allows for `cgi` backwards compatibility, I decided to start with that.
However I could not get the `examples/tiny-fcgi.c` to work with `lighttpd`, it yielded an `internal server errror 500`, the same configuration allows to run the `lighttpd` example program (http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ModFastCGI, below `C/C++ FastCGI on lightty named socket`) flawless. However it is totally unclear to me why the default supplied example would not work.

Questions:

1. What is wrong with the examples/tiny-fcgi.c example from the reference implementation causing lighttpd to return error 500?
2. Which implementation of fastcgi is preferable for c++ development (fcgi_stdio, fcgiapp, Other)? (There is something for streams in the fcgi pack, however I failed to find good/any documentation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested the [unmodified example](http://www.fastcgi.com/om_archive/kit/examples/tiny-fcgi.c) (Ubuntu/13.10/amd-64, Apache/2.4.6, libapache2-mod-fastcgi/2.4.7~0910052141-1.1, libfcgi-dev/2.4.0-8.1ubuntu4) and it runs ok:

```
manuelz@garibaldi:~$ curl habrich/tiny-fcgi
<title>FastCGI Hello! (C, fcgi_stdio library)</title>
<h1>FastCGI Hello! (C, fcgi_stdio library)</h1>
Request number 2 running on host <i>habrich</i>
```

Answers:

1. Hard to tell without knowing your configuration, but here's a shot in the dark: `getenv` will return `NULL` if `SERVER_NAME` is [undefined](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/getenv/).
2. `fcgiapp` is the base implementation: I would use that one for new development. `fcgi_stdio` is a wrapper for compatibility with CGI: use that for migrating legacy CGI projects. [Quote](http://www.fastcgi.com/devkit/doc/fcgi-devel-kit.htm#S3.2):

> fcgi_stdio is implemented as a thin layer on top of fcgiapp
>   
>   You can find decent documentation for `fcgiapp` in the [fcgiapp.h](http://www.fastcgi.com/devkit/include/fcgiapp.h) header.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know whether your problem has the same origin as mine had, but at least it has the same symptoms.

There are different versions of the tiny-fcgi example.  I first tried the one given [here](http://www.fastcgi.com/devkit/doc/fastcgi-prog-guide/ch2c.htm) (example 1).  This failed with an internal server error.  However, the example given [here](http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/node/6?q=node/21#S3.1) (which does basically the same) works.  The small but crucial difference is that the working code uses

```
getenv("SERVER_NAME")
```

instead of

```
getenv("SERVER_HOSTNAME")
```

Answer (score 0):

not exactly the same for me, but if i avoid using `getenv` the example runs without errors, have to discover why `getenv` leads into error